# Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql

Since a couple of days, I have "lock wait timeout exceeded" when running only certain UPDATE statements; and even an INSERT one (for a brand new table). It seemed to have started happening since upgrading from (probably) MySQL 8.0.31 to 8.0.34.

I've googled a lot already, and ran queries such as SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST. Only the event scheduler and a task related to compressing GTID table seemed suspicious, I've managed to disable it as I don't think they're needed in my case.

Also tried stuff like this, but no results.

check MySQL open tables

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE In_use > 0;
```

Check pending InnoDB transactions

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_trx ORDER BY trx_started;
```

Check lock dependency - what blocks what

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_locks;
```

I'm not sure about the engine status; is this perhaps worrying?
TRANSACTIONS

```
Trx id counter 30988819
Purge done for trx's n:o < 30988811 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION
---TRANSACTION 283593565281880, not started 0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 283593565281104, not started 0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 283593565280328, not started 0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 283593565279552, not started 0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 283593565278000, not started 0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 283593565277224, not started 1 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 1 row lock(s)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your lock wait timeout setting?

Comment: no you have a query update i believe that tries to access the same rows and it takes for one of them to long to finish, you should start to review the queries you got and see if you can spedd them up

Comment: It's currently set to 50 seconds. Already tried increasing it to 120, 600, 5000. Made no difference.

At one point, I made sure there's only one connection (command line from which I also attempted the same statements) after rebooting the server.